# Using label text in linq where parameter

Tags: c#, bootstrap-4

Basically i tried to do what is recommended but somehow it doesn't work. the problem is i cannot take value of selected item in dropdown to textbox value. what i observed is JS code isn't triggered. What could be the problem?

my codes are;

HTML

```
                <div class="dropdown show col-md-2 p-1">
                    <a class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm dropdown-toggle p-1" href="#" role="button" id="dropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" runat="server">Load Evaluation
                    </a>

                    <div id="dropdown"  runat="server" class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuLink">
                    </div>

                </div>

                <div>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="dropLabel" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnTextChanged="dropLabel_OnTextChanged" Style ="display:block"></asp:TextBox>
                    
                </div>
```

JS

```
$('#dropdown a').on('click', function () {

$('#dropLabel').val(this.text());
sessionStorage.setItem('label1', $(this).text());
location.reload(true);
```

})

C#

```
    protected void dropLabel_OnTextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var labelText = (sender as TextBox).Text;
        //... do something with the text.

        A3toSqlDataContext ctx4 = new A3toSqlDataContext();
        var yukle = from c in ctx4.A3_Coaching
                    where c.name == labelText
                    select c;
```

C# for a tag including

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            A3toSqlDataContext ctx = new A3toSqlDataContext();
            var alp = from c in ctx.A3_Coaching
                      select c.name;

            foreach (var item in alp)
            {

                HtmlGenericControl anchor = new HtmlGenericControl("a");
                anchor.Attributes.Add("href", "#");
                anchor.InnerHtml = Convert.ToString(item);
                anchor.Attributes.Add("class", "dropdown-item");


                dropdown.Controls.Add(anchor);

            }

        }




    }
```

Comment: is there anyone can help me?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, that your `dropLabel` might be a server-side control, but the actual javascript is happening on the client, so your asp.net application will not be aware of this until you do a postback to the server.

You should be able to do this, if you convert your `droplabel` to an invisible `Textbox`, that will do a Postback for you, when its text changes:

```
<div>
    <asp:Textbox id="dropLabel" runat="server"
               AutoPostback="true"
               OnTextChanged="dropLabel_OnTextChanged"
               style="display:none">
    </asp:Textbox>
</div>
```

CodeBehind:

```
protected void dropLabel_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     var labelText = (sender as TextBox).Text
     //... do something with the text.
}
```

Make sure you check for a PostBack in your `Page_Load` to not re-load everything and possibly overwrite your state using `if(!IsPostBack) { /*... do regular Page_Load*/}`

Comment: thank you very much. i tried your proposal but i couldn't use "labelText"

            if ( labelText != null)
            {
                A3toSqlDataContext ctx4 = new A3toSqlDataContext();
                var yukle = from c in ctx4.A3_Coaching
                            where c.name == labelText
                            select c;
            }

Comment: Actually it works in CoreBehind but i cannot get selected item text from js code. is there something that i should change in JS code?